# How to set up a service principle account in azure automation

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm using azure automation to automate a process with a Powershell Workflow Runbook. In that process I connect to MSOnline and Exchange with a Credential:

```
   # Pull credential from Automation assets
   $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "CredentialName"

   # Connect To Microsoft online
   Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

   # Connect to Exchange Online
   $ExchangeOnlineSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -Name $ConnectionName
   Import-Module (Import-PSSession -Session $ExchangeOnlineSession -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking) -Global
```

This works but I don't want to save credentials of an account with permissions, the $cred.

I read and (thought I) understood that this could be done with a Service Principle Account. The problem is that I don't find it good described in order for me to make it work, although I have tried many times.

Any information is welcome

Comment: Do you wan to create sp account for automation or create sp in automation?

Comment: Are you looking for [Create an Azure service principal with Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azurermps-6.1.0)?

Comment: @Yang I want to create a sp account for automation, so I can authenticate the msol and exchange connections.

Comment: @Wang I want to create a sp account, but the most important thing is to use it in automation

Comment: Pleae refer to this article for automatic login Azure with service principal:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40062.automating-azure-login-for-powershell-scripts-using-service-principal.aspx

Also, remember to assign a role to your sp in IAM of your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you're using "Azure Automation" to automate a process, I believe you must have provisioned an Azure Automation Account to hold the PS Runbook & authenticate to Azure resources.

When you setup an Azure Automation Account, there's a built-in feature "Run As Accounts". It creates a Run-As account which takes care of the following tasks for the user:

- Create a Service Principal in Azure AD
- Create a Certificate
- Assigns the Contributor Role-Based Access Control (RBAC), which manages Azure Resource Manager resources by using runbooks

[image]

One point to note here is that, the Service Principal for a Run as Account does not have permissions to read Azure AD by default. If you want to add permissions to read or manage Azure AD, you'll need to grant the permissions on the service principal under [API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis).

Once you're all set with Run As Account, you can use the account and retrieve the connection with `Get-AzAutomationConnection`

You can refer this documentation for more details: [Manage Azure Automation Run As Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account)

Hope this helps!